# Accessing data files from within an egg

Tags: python, egg

I have a package with a default json file in case the user hasnt supplied one
        `data = pkgutil.get_data(__name__, "deprecated.json")`

when running stand-alone this works fine

But if I run `python setup.py install` to create `my.egg`
The run `easy_install my.egg`
Finally start the executable I get an error message `` [Errno 2 nosuch file or director: `d:\\work\\pythonvenv\\lib\\site-packages\\my.egg\\PackageName\\depercate.json ``

```
    return loader.get_data(resource_name)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 972, in get_data
```

I thought the purpose of using pkgutil.get_data was to prevent this type of issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `setup.py` file to include `package_data` as in https://docs.python.org/3.8/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data

```
setup(
    ...,
    package_data={'pkgName': ["path/to/deprecated.json"]},
)
```

Another way to achieve the same behavior is to create a `MANIFEST.in` file with the contents `include path/to/deprecated.json` and then in your `setup` function include the argument `include_package_data=True`. This is detailed in https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html.